# Ms access VBA - run Detail_Paint() only once on Report_Load()

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've built a report that ranks customers based on certain parameters (like contracting, compliance and communication) and used the built-in conditional formation to compare each field of an entry to the other fields and paint it accordingly. However, the coloring of fields takes ages, scrolling within the report is laggy und some of the fields loose their format on the run.

Thus, I intend to implement a conditional color scale formatting in vba.

This code is triggered via *Report_Load()*:

```
col_fields = Array("Rating", "Contracting", "Compliance", "Communication")
cred = Array(240, 200)
cgreen = Array(160, 240)
cblue = Array(160, 166)

cred_step = (cred(1) - cred(0)) / DCount("*", "eval_7_final")
cgreen_step = (cgreen(1) - cgreen(0)) / DCount("*", "eval_7_final")
cblue_step = (cblue(1) - cblue(0)) / DCount("*", "eval_7_final")
```

For explanation: cred defines the RGB margins for red. cred_step will be multiplied with the rank and added to the lower margin to get the final red-value for each single ranked entry and field (I might switch to a relative, continuous coloring rather than an interceptive scale in the future).

This code is triggered by *Detail_Paint()*:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(col_fields)
rank = DCount("Rating", "eval_7_final", col_fields(i) & " > '" & Me.Controls(col_fields(i)) & "'")
Me.Controls(col_fields(i)).BackColor = RGB(cred(1) - cred_step * rank, cgreen(1) - cgreen_step * rank, cblue(1) - cblue_step * rank)
Next i
```

For each single field, the individual rank for that value is computed and the field colorized accordingly.
Strangely, the formatting runs through each detail section several times which slows down the progress and each fields are formatted again when scrolling.

I tried to implement a counter within the colorization-loop and use an IF-statement to prevent the script from running, if the counter reaches a certain value (i.e. counts of entries * number of colorized fields). However, whenever I try to interrupt the script, all rows adapt the format of a single row.

[image: before and after changing the if condition]

What I would need would be a solution that prevents format-updates after the initial load-event the details_paint() events have run through.

Comment: Have you tried using the on_Format event?

Comment: on_Format is working smoothly for print preview only. But not in report view, which I prefer since I want to add a button (see column "Rank" in the image) to open a detailed view for each entry.

Comment: It sounds like this should rather be a continuous **form** than a report.

Comment: I agree and have to admit, that I initially created it in form of a continuous form, then switched to a report for some reasons I can't recall anymore. I might verey well switch to a form again, though it would be nice if there is a way to deal with that issue in a report.

Comment: Just tried to switch it into a form and remembered the reason: The user should be able to see the report on screen and select individual entries and he should be able to print it in a decent layout. The latter one drove me to reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little information to be found about when or why to use the new `On Paint` event (added in Acc2007), and how to do it efficiently.

It is run multiple times, when a control is redrawn (e.g. when scrolling). So it doesn't seem like a good place to implement formatting that needs calculations, especially if they include database lookups.

If you exit out of the event procedure after the first run, the control won't retain the individual formatting you applied in the first run.

In the end, I'm pretty sure that **Conditional formatting**, with all its weaknesses, will be your best option.

Move the calculation of rank per field out of the Conditional formatting, and into your record source, this should speed things up.

Comment: I added the ranks for each field to the data source query. It will probably still slow down the progress when scrolling once the database hits a certain size, but its way faster now. Thanks